# Outlook hangup in first time forward or reply or new emial

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office-2007

I use `Microsoft Outlook` as email communication. When I login in `windows-xp`, outlook load and connect to server well. but for first time, when I want forward or reply or new email, outlook hangup and I have to kill its process(by `Task-Manager`) and again open it and forward or reply or new email.

What is problem?